# Double sequence $(x_{i,j})$ such that for every $j$ the sequence $x_{i,j}$ converges to the same limit $\bar{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider an double sequence $(x_{i,j}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that for every $j$

$$ x_{i,j} \rightarrow \bar{x} \qquad \text{as} \qquad i \rightarrow \infty$$

for some $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. This means for every $j$ the sequence $(x_{i,j})$ converges to the same limit point $\bar{x}$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$.

**Can I argue in the following way:**

Then for every $i$ the sequence $(x_{i,j})$ admits an accumulation point denoted $x_{i}$.

It holds that $x_{i} \rightarrow \bar{x}$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO. Suppose $x_{i,j}=j$ when $j\ge i$ and $x_{i,j}=0$ when $j<i .$ Then for every $j$ we have $\lim_{i\to\infty}x_{i,j}=0.$ But for a fixed $i$ we have $j\ge i\implies x_{i,j}=j$ so the sequence $(x_{i,j})_j$ has no accumulation point.

Comment: Great (simple) example. Thank you.

Comment: Dover Publications is a great source for cheap re-prints of old textbooks & monographs on math & science. I recommend Infinite Sequences And Series by Bromwich. (Different editions have slightly different titles.)

Comment: Many thanks for that recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you cannot argue like that. Maybe I miscomputed, but the following should be a counterexample.

Let $x_{i,j}= \left( 1+\frac 1 i\right)^{i+j}$, then for each fixed $j \in \mathbb N$ you have
$$\lim_{i\to \infty} \left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{i}\left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{j}=e\cdot 1 =e$$
but for a fixed $i \in \mathbb N$ you have $$\lim_{j\to \infty} \left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{i}\left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{j}=\left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{i}\cdot \lim_{j\to \infty}\left( 1+\frac 1i\right)^{j} = \infty\,$$
since $1+\frac 1i >1$.

Comment: I think your example is right. Many thanks.